# What's the best practice for amending a merged remote branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

For example, I've finished a feature branch, pushed and merged it into the remote develop branch. After 3 days, I find a typo on that branch, then what's the best way to amend that branch. Create a new branch to correct that trivial mistake or re-work on the old branch? Could you please give an example with git commands for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're talking about a policy issue, not really a technical one. The technical part is the same - you'd treat it as any other change. Another branch to be merged in, if that is your workflow.

Whether or not you're committing that new typo on a *new branch* or the just-merged *old branch* doesn't matter to git, the tree looks the same in both cases.

### New commits, no amending, merged in later

Here's how it would look like after the merging of your minor commit:

```
A-B-C-D-G-H-I-J (develop, newMergedBranch or oldMergedBranch)
 \   /       /
  E-F----Typo
```

---

One place where it does matter is the merge commit itself. It would say `Merged in branchName`. So depending upon how you want it to look (if the merge commits aren't being edited) you can choose which branch name you want to use.

### Amend then merge again

Clarification about effects of amending, in response to comment:
Whether or not amending is bad practice depends on whether people are now working off of D. If someone made commits on top of D, and then you amend an earlier commit (say F, using `git rebase -i`), you'd change everything downstream of it.

**NOTE: For all of the D's below, C is a parent. D' is a merge commit.**

```
A-B-C-D--G-H-I-J (other develop)
 \   /       
  E-F  D' (your develop, oldBranch)
   \F'/ (Typo)
```

To resolve this (without forced pushes - with forced updates, all of the pulls from D have to force pull, potentially losing changes if they're not aware. They'd first run into pull conflicts, even if they're doing everything right. This is the reason why history amending for exposed branches is considered bad practice), one would have to merge your develop:

```
A-B-C-D--G-H-I-J-K (develop, old branch)
 \   /          / 
  E-F  D'-------
   \F'/ (Typo)
```

To clarify, D' isn't downstream of F in this picture.

Summing up, this is exactly like the old scenario, the one without amending commits. It's just that if you amend commits, it looks "uglier". It's bad practice to force push though. Likely you wouldn't have access to do that anyway.

### Amend, rebase, force push

If you rebase the rest of develop and force push, then someone who pulled will have:

```
A-B-C-D-G-H-I-J-L1-L2-L3 (other person's local develop, L1- being local commits)
 \   /           
  E-F  
   \F'-D'-G'-H'-I'-J' (develop)
```

Then they'll get conflicts when they pull the new rebased develop, and then they'd have to merge again. Or do something even more complicated, like a rebase, to achieve:

```
A-B--C
 \    \ 
  E-F'-D'-G'-H'-I'-J'-L1-L2-L3 (develop)
```

Crucially, they'll have to know to do this (*evrey single one of them*), or they'll just merge and make all YOUR efforts in vain - resulting in a merge again.

---

About policy:

You've *committed* to that code, there's no changing it now. There's no amending, no history overwriting. You'll have to live with it.

If the change to be made is critical, you would've gotten it done by now. If not, but something like a pet peeve, it now depends on what your commit policy is. Does you(r organization, team, etc. as a collective decision) want an entire commit sitting there just to correct a typo?

Most teams are fine with that. Nobody's going to be hurt or annoyed enough to bring it up. If it's likely that someone else is going to work on that area of the codebase and will come across that typo and will be annoyed, by all means fix it - no two ways about it.

If not, and it's mostly isolated, then what I'd do in your situation is to put that change on a branch somewhere, perhaps in your stash. When you next have to work with that codebase again, you can add this typo change to it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, you're right that this question is mainly on policy, and I totally agree with you on the policy side. Actually, on the technical side, I was also wondering if it's possible to amend a typo mistake to the original merge which is the D node in your example. I guess it should be a bad practice right?

Comment: Updated to reflect the question you asked! It's not technically bad practice, just looks ugly. Requires a merge anyway.

Comment: Added a way to make it so there's only one merge overall. Which is what you were asking about anyway.

Comment: TODO: Need to update this to be actually coherant and readable for people with no context.

Comment: Finally got time to read through this. It's a really good explanation. Thanks!